# mysql copy column and convert string

Tags: mysql

what wrong with this code i want to copy Hno to Hno2 but change from / to . such as 12/3 to 12.3 i use mysql

```
update set hno2 =   SELECT REPLACE(hno, '/', '.') FROM member;
```

`Hno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hno2` decimal(8,4) NOT NULL,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update member
set hhno2 = replace(CAST(hno AS char), '/', '.');
```

Comment: It's the other way around: hhno2 is a decimal. so it has to be `update member
set hhno2 = CAST(replace(hno, '/', '.'), AS decimal);`

Comment: And another way is `update member set hno2 = replace(concat(hno, ''), '/', '.')`